# React-Native Mysql Select Query

Tags: react-native

Have a nice day. I'm using React-Native. I have two classes. I want to capture the data I fetched in the second class in the first class. I want to query this data when doing a sql query. I want to search the sql command based on this data. As you can see in the code, var sql = 'SELECT ID FROM ...TBL_STT where value';
I am searching by value value registered with. But this code doesn't work. Or how can I use the select sql command based on this data without using php in Mysql in a single class. I want to search tables by the name entered by the user.

**1.Class**

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
 klikGet(){
    var url = 'http://localhost:3210/';
    axios.get(url)
    .then((ambilData) => {
      console.log(ambilData.data);

      this.setState({
        dataku: ambilData.data,
      }) 
    })
  };
if (name== this.state.itemsKULLANICI && pass == this.state.itemsSIFRE){
            AsyncStorage.setItem('ambil', this.state.itemsKULLANICI);
}
```

**2.Class**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

let db = mysql.createConnection({
   ...'
});

db.connect();


app.get('/', function(req,res){
   AsyncStorage.getItem('ambit').then(value =>
var sql = 'SELECT ID FROM ....TBL_STT where value';
db.query(sql, (err, result)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    res.send(result);
});
});
    );
app.listen(3210, ()=>{
});
```